# Unity 2D enemies leaving corpses and walking over them

Tags: unity-game-engine, side-scroller, collider

I'm doing a sidescroller where enemies will leave corpses after they are killed. I've tried to do colliders, but any following enemy will glitch horribly when walking over a corpse. Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a bit incomplete, but a solution could be to assign the enemy sprites a particular layer (Edit -> Project Settings -> Tags and Layers), and ensure that they don't interact with each other by using Unity's Physics project settings (Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics 2D).  The inspector will display a triangular matrix, where the row and column intersections define which layers may collide with each other.  Ensure that the row and column intersection for your enemy layer is unchecked.  Enemies will no longer collide with each other, and shouldn't exhibit the glitching.  However, this may be due to scripting present on the enemies, so more investigation likely will be warranted.